# Iteratively minimize $\|AX\|_F$ subject to equality and inequality constraints

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, numerical-optimization, quadratic-programming

I would like to know what is the most effective iterative algorithm to the following optimization problem:

Given $A \in \mathbb R^{n  \times n} $ find a rectangular matrix  $X \in \mathbb R^{n  \times m} $, where $n>m$,  such that the Frobenius Norm  $\|AX\|_F$  is minimized subject to all of the following conditions:

1. $X \mathbf{1_m} = \mathbf{1_n} $  where $\mathbf{1_m} \in \mathbb R^{m \times 1} $  and $\mathbf{1_n} \in \mathbb R^{n \times 1} $  are vectors with all their entries set to one.
2. The matrix entries have the condition $X_{i_pj_p}=1$ for a set of indices $(i_p, j_p) $ with $p \in [1,m]$. The chosen indices have the limitation  $i_p \neq i_q $ and $j_p \neq j_q $ for $p \neq q$
3. $X_{ij} \ge 0 $ for all $i,j$

Edit 1:
I agree that "Most effective" is a vague requirement so I will try to clarify. The Matrices $A$ and $X$ are large (around a million rows) and sparse and hence I would like an iterative algorithm. I am willing to write custom code, but would like to know which algorithm is robust.

Comment: What prohibits the choice $A = 0$?

Comment: The question was incorrect. I corrected it now. $A$ is given. $X$ needs to be found.

Comment: The constraint number 2 is not really a constraint for an iterative solver, it gives a part of the shape of $X$ and constraint $1$ is about the eigenvalues of $X$.

Comment: About constraint number 1, how does one define eigenvalues for rectangular matrices?

Comment: Do you really need $>$ in condition 3? Will $\ge$ be enough?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes indeed I do not need strict inequality

Comment: Eigenvalues are defined for linear maps as $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ such that there exists $x$ such that $f(x) = \lambda x$.

Comment: Just to make sure: You do realize the problem is a standard quadratic program to begin with (assuming the set $i_q$ and $j_q$ are given) and thus easily solved using standard QP strategies?

Comment: That is certainly true, and yet a proximal gradient algorithm would likely be quite effective here. Of course, the original poster didn't specify what he meant by "most effective" so it's not clear what would be preferred. And of course, the proximal gradient approach would require custom code.

Comment: @Johan Löfberg, I have to admit my ignorance as I do not know much about QP strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since

$$\| \mathrm A \mathrm X \|_F^2 = \| \mbox{vec} (\mathrm A \mathrm X) \|_2^2 = \| (\mathrm I_m \otimes \mathrm A) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \|_2^2 = \mbox{vec}^{\top} (\mathrm X) (\mathrm I_m \otimes \mathrm A^{\top}) (\mathrm I_m \otimes \mathrm A) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X)$$

you have a **quadratic program** (QP) in $\mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \in \mathbb R^{mn}$

$$\boxed{\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \mbox{vec}^{\top} (\mathrm X) (\mathrm I_m \otimes \mathrm A^{\top}) (\mathrm I_m \otimes \mathrm A) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X)\\ \text{subject to} & (1_m^{\top} \otimes \mathrm I_n) \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) = 1_n\\ & (\mathrm e_j \otimes \mathrm e_i)^{\top} \, \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) = c_{ij} \quad \forall (i,j) \in \mathcal{C}\\ & \mbox{vec} (\mathrm X) \geq 0_{mn}\end{array}}$$

where the $c_{ij}$'s are the constraints on the $(i,j)$-th entries of $\mathrm X$, and $\mathcal{C} \subset [n] \times [m]$ is the set of the indices of the constrained entries.

Comment: Thanks Rodrigo for your answer. I really appreciate it and have learnt something new. However I was looking more for a description or name of an algorithm to solve the optimization problem for large sparse matrices. Could you please point out a few in this answer?

Comment: @hakeem Not my area of expertise. The point of my answer was to show that your problem can be written as a standard QP, for which there surely are solvers. My goal was to point the right direction, so you know which terms to google.